# En este caso se incuye el directorio migrations en el git o no?

Tags: git, migration

A un sistema web ya en producción le voy agregando funcionalidades nuevas que incluyen modificaciones al esquema de base de datos. A medida que desarrollo subo al GitLab de nuestra organización los cambios y el administrador del nodo los pasa al servidor de producción. Anteriormente en el servidor de producción se hacía `doctrine:schema:update` para lidiar con los cambios a la base de datos, pero ahora he empezado a usar ***DoctrineMigrationsBundle***; mi duda es si los ficheros de migración los genero yo en mi entorno de desarrollo y los debo subir al control de versiones para ser ejecutados, o los dejo fuera del control de versiones y el administrador del servidor en producción tiene que encargarse de generarlos y ejecutarlos??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**La respuesta es sí**.

¿Se podría hacer también sin añadir la carpeta en el control de versiones? Si, pero en ocasiones habría que trabajar 2 veces (por lo menos), y si hubiera algún problema costaría más tiempo encontrar de dónde proviene. Es decir, mayor probabilidad de errores y problemas.

**Explicación**

Al crear un nuevo archivo con los cambios en tus entidades (`php bin/console make:migration`) al comienzo del archivo que te genera te encuentras esto:

```
/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
```

Es decir, te está facilitando el trabajo creando una versión, pero como es posible que, los campos no estén en el orden que tú quieres (a mí esto me suele ocurrir con frecuencia), o quieras añadir/quitar registros, o quieras dejar una descripción, etc, te dice que modifiques el archivo a tus necesidades.

Si haces alguna modificación en tu archivo y no lo pones en el repositorio, al querer poner en producción la nueva funcionalidad y generar de nuevo el archivo, habría que acordarse de los cambios que había que hacer (trabajar 2 veces). Y si trabajas con más desarrolladores, tod@s tendrían que acordarse de las modificaciones a realizar. Si lo pones en el repositorio, en todos los casos será tán fácil como ejecutar `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

Otro tema es que, al haberlo probado en el entorno de pruebas, te aseguras de que la migración que se va a poner en producción ya está validada en otro entorno. Siempre da más confianza y tranquilidad.

También ocurre, que si el equipo de desarrollo es grande, y se suben modificaciones en BBDD en tareas diferentes, al poner en producción y realizar todos los cambios en una sola versión, si ocurre algún problema relacionado con BBDD sería más laborioso encontrar de qué tarea proviene el error.

Y, aunque quizás este último punto no sea tan importante (o sí), si en tu desarrollo creas varias versiones y en producción se realizan los cambios en una sola, los registros de la tabla `doctrine_migration_versions` serán diferentes.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.